# Запятая или точка с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, точка-с-запятой

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой знак ставить на месте (). Точку с запятой или запятую? "Я размышлял, стоит ли звонить ей() не знал, вспомнит ли она меня".

Answer (score 5):

Или запятую, или двоеточие, потому что здесь причинные связи:

"Я размышлял, стоит ли звонить ей (почему?): (потому что) не знал, вспомнит ли она меня".

Точка с запятой ставится, когда разнородные явления объединяются в одну картину, а здесь явно связанные события.

А лучше не объединять их, оформить как два предложения:

"Я размышлял, стоит ли звонить ей. Я ведь не знал, вспомнит ли она меня".

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ.

Answer (score 3):

По всей видимости, здесь нужна запятая: это сложноподчиненное предложение с неоднородным подчинением, в котором одна придаточная относится к сказуемому главного предложения "размышлял", а другая - к сказуемому "знал", принадлежащему все той же главной части. Таким образом, сказуемые "размышлял" и "знал" однородны.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

В приведенных примерах автор может выбирать между следующими вариантами: 1)  он не хочет акцентировать внимание на следственно-причинной связи между предложениями - тогда это запятая; 2) Он хочет обозначить эту связь, она для него важна - тогда А) двоеточие, если есть желание предупредить о последующем разъяснении (увеличенная пауза в устной речи) или Б) лучше тире, если пояснительное сообщение будет носить добавочный характер.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь достаточно запятой, так как связь между частями сложного предложения достаточно тесная.

Comment: Спасибо. Извините за глупый вопрос, но изменится ли что-то, если предложение слегка изменить: "Она долго размышляла о том, не сплю ли я в этот поздний час, не знала, стоит ли мне звонить". Так и останется запятая? Просто не вполне разобралась с правилом про точку с запятой.

Comment: И здесь я не вижу оснований для постановки точки с запятой. По ссылке
(http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=tz) приведены все случаи употребления этого знака. Вам будут интересны пункты 133 и 134.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, прочту.